# Path of steepest descent with a known starting and end point

Tags: r, raster, terrain

I have an elevation raster (Digital Elevation Model). I want to find the path of the steepest descent between two known points. From a cell, you can only move to the surrounding seven cells (discounting one previous cell) and I want that cell to be selected based on the steepest descent. If all the seven surrounding cells are higher than the current cell, I want to select the cell with the mildest ascent and proceed. All the cells with no data should be ignored. I have only managed to calculate the slope raster (I know, it's the easiest step) and am not sure how to proceed from there.

Sample data set to work with
[image]

```
fp <- sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(333350,3060410)) # starting point
lp <- sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(333100,3060600)) # end point

#raster
    dput(rast)
    new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "FLT4S", 
        byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -3.4e+38, NAchanged = FALSE, 
        nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
        blockrows = 16L, blockcols = 128L, driver = "", open = FALSE), 
        data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, 1208.45349121094, 1207.15441894531, 1207.19006347656, 
        1207.94274902344, 1207.89782714844, 1207.94274902344, 1209.11303710938, 
        1210.1640625, 1208.50305175781, 1209.26330566406, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.56213378906, 
        1207.99792480469, 1207.19848632812, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 
        1208.01794433594, 1208.43347167969, 1208.52490234375, 1210.61877441406, 
        1209.56994628906, 1212.35241699219, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.55212402344, 1208.19763183594, 
        1207.61181640625, 1207.9072265625, 1208.43347167969, 1208.53259277344, 
        1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 1209.91125488281, 1209.72192382812, 
        1217.07543945312, 1219.02136230469, 1219.72485351562, 1217.35620117188, 
        1214.68359375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        1208.24816894531, 1208.21142578125, 1207.71325683594, 1207.91076660156, 
        1208.19030761719, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53442382812, 1208.56506347656, 
        1211.30285644531, 1215.82885742188, 1214.61682128906, 1221.67639160156, 
        1220.3544921875, 1219.9892578125, 1217.69470214844, 1221.14685058594, 
        1219.81823730469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        1208.55249023438, 1208.02697753906, 1208.017578125, 1207.400390625, 
        1208.65942382812, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53625488281, 1208.76940917969, 
        1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 
        1217.29479980469, 1222.43395996094, 1220.53955078125, 1222.69262695312, 
        1221.01965332031, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        1208.05090332031, 1207.9970703125, 1207.96997070312, 1208.05041503906, 
        1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 
        1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 
        1222.4541015625, 1220.85107421875, 1221.82141113281, 1216.05773925781, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.44177246094, 
        1208.52172851562, 1208.26806640625, 1208.46484375, 1208.78295898438, 
        1207.81494140625, 1208.16723632812, 1208.69140625, 1209.5849609375, 
        1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.720703125, 1213.89770507812, 
        1214.76220703125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, 1209.41796875, 1208.56091308594, 1208.10803222656, 
        1208.53002929688, 1208.42626953125, 1207.88256835938, 1208.81066894531, 
        1208.83459472656, 1209.5849609375, 1209.52807617188, 1209.81579589844, 
        1214.59741210938, 1223.80065917969, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.49841308594, 
        1209.14697265625, 1208.54370117188, 1208.89050292969, 1209.81579589844, 
        1209.81579589844, 1214.78759765625, 1221.84899902344, 1223.90710449219, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, 1208.6904296875, 1208.94995117188, 1209.23315429688, 
        1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1214.1171875, 1215.07580566406, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.83178710938, 1208.76831054688, 1209.67565917969, 
        1209.67565917969, 1211.46594238281, 1214.94274902344, 1215.39904785156, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, 1209.25732421875, 1208.86218261719, 1209.048828125, 
        1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1211.82763671875, 1215.14599609375, 
        1215.67370605469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.06079101562, 1209.17163085938, 
        1208.79455566406, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1213.59326171875, 
        1220.58471679688, 1217.48803710938, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.30834960938, 
        1209.05725097656, 1210.30346679688, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
        1215.83471679688, 1222.40283203125, 1218.2578125, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, 1209.61926269531, 1210.16052246094, 1210.56823730469, 
        1210.79309082031, 1210.46276855469, 1214.73291015625, 1216.96398925781, 
        1219.07653808594, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.46716308594, 1209.22875976562, 
        1210.47521972656, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1212.83312988281, 
        1216.43481445312, 1219.17358398438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.00036621094, 
        1209.9521484375, 1209.96520996094, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
        1213.79821777344, 1217.90661621094, 1219.22473144531, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, 1209.54418945312, 1210.26818847656, 1210.0283203125, 
        1210.03039550781, 1210.0283203125, 1212.66833496094, 1216.18420410156, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, 1209.45166015625, 1209.70434570312, 1209.33239746094, 
        1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.15905761719, 1212.17797851562, 
        1214.48999023438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.94604492188, 1210.36206054688, 
        1210.103515625, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.44226074219, 
        1214.18041992188, NA, NA), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, 
            fromdisk = FALSE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
            haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1207.15441894531, max = 1223.90710449219, 
            band = 1L, unit = "", names = "nakkhu_hosp_10m"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
            type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
            names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
        extent = new("Extent", xmin = 333003.9801, xmax = 333403.9801, 
            ymin = 3060402.4038, ymax = 3060602.4038), rotated = FALSE, 
        rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 40L, nrows = 20L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
        history = list(), z = list())
```

**Edit: Response to nniloc's answer**

I think it finds the least distance path. What I want is different. See the image below when I applied your method to a different raster. Looks like the path skips the surrounding cells when it finds a shorter route.

[image]

Comment: If you have `terra` pkg have a look at `?terra::terrain` arg v = 'flowdir' or 'TPI' how it is generally calculated  as discussed in Details.

Comment: Thank you. `terra::terrain` is indeed helpful. But I am struggling to define a path based on the results from `terra::terrain`. Any suggestion for a way forward?

Comment: Another approach using `topmodel` presented below.

Comment: A further approach employing `deldir`, finalization remains to be done, but the sketch is there.

Answer (score 2):

The `leastcostpath` [package](https://github.com/josephlewis/leastcostpath) has a function `create_lcp` which allows you to define an `origin` and `destination`.

EDIT: Adding in "barriers" based on [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leastcostpath/vignettes/leastcostpath-1.html#creating-and-incorporating-barriers-within-cost-surfaces). On the example data it didn't noticeably change the path, so I can't be sure if it is working properly.

```
library(leastcostpath)

rast_slope <- create_slope_cs(rast, cost_function = 'tobler', neighbours = 8)

# add barrier anywhere rast is equal to NA
rast_nas <- is.na(rast)
rast_nas[rast_nas == 0] <- NA
rast_barrier <- create_barrier_cs(rast, rast_nas, field = 0, background = 1)


rast_slope_barrier <- rast_slope * rast_barrier
#plot(raster(rast_slope_barrier), col = grey.colors(100))


lcp <- create_lcp(rast_slope_barrier, fp, lp, TRUE)

plot(rast)
lines(lcp)
points(fp)
points(lp)
```

### [image]

Data

```
library(raster)

rast <- new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "FLT4S", 
                                      byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -3.4e+38, NAchanged = FALSE, 
                                      nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
                                      blockrows = 16L, blockcols = 128L, driver = "", open = FALSE), 
            data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, 1208.45349121094, 1207.15441894531, 1207.19006347656, 
                                                      1207.94274902344, 1207.89782714844, 1207.94274902344, 1209.11303710938, 
                                                      1210.1640625, 1208.50305175781, 1209.26330566406, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.56213378906, 
                                                      1207.99792480469, 1207.19848632812, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 
                                                      1208.01794433594, 1208.43347167969, 1208.52490234375, 1210.61877441406, 
                                                      1209.56994628906, 1212.35241699219, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.55212402344, 1208.19763183594, 
                                                      1207.61181640625, 1207.9072265625, 1208.43347167969, 1208.53259277344, 
                                                      1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 1209.91125488281, 1209.72192382812, 
                                                      1217.07543945312, 1219.02136230469, 1219.72485351562, 1217.35620117188, 
                                                      1214.68359375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      1208.24816894531, 1208.21142578125, 1207.71325683594, 1207.91076660156, 
                                                      1208.19030761719, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53442382812, 1208.56506347656, 
                                                      1211.30285644531, 1215.82885742188, 1214.61682128906, 1221.67639160156, 
                                                      1220.3544921875, 1219.9892578125, 1217.69470214844, 1221.14685058594, 
                                                      1219.81823730469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      1208.55249023438, 1208.02697753906, 1208.017578125, 1207.400390625, 
                                                      1208.65942382812, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53625488281, 1208.76940917969, 
                                                      1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 
                                                      1217.29479980469, 1222.43395996094, 1220.53955078125, 1222.69262695312, 
                                                      1221.01965332031, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      1208.05090332031, 1207.9970703125, 1207.96997070312, 1208.05041503906, 
                                                      1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 
                                                      1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 
                                                      1222.4541015625, 1220.85107421875, 1221.82141113281, 1216.05773925781, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.44177246094, 
                                                      1208.52172851562, 1208.26806640625, 1208.46484375, 1208.78295898438, 
                                                      1207.81494140625, 1208.16723632812, 1208.69140625, 1209.5849609375, 
                                                      1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.720703125, 1213.89770507812, 
                                                      1214.76220703125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, 1209.41796875, 1208.56091308594, 1208.10803222656, 
                                                      1208.53002929688, 1208.42626953125, 1207.88256835938, 1208.81066894531, 
                                                      1208.83459472656, 1209.5849609375, 1209.52807617188, 1209.81579589844, 
                                                      1214.59741210938, 1223.80065917969, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.49841308594, 
                                                      1209.14697265625, 1208.54370117188, 1208.89050292969, 1209.81579589844, 
                                                      1209.81579589844, 1214.78759765625, 1221.84899902344, 1223.90710449219, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, 1208.6904296875, 1208.94995117188, 1209.23315429688, 
                                                      1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1214.1171875, 1215.07580566406, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.83178710938, 1208.76831054688, 1209.67565917969, 
                                                      1209.67565917969, 1211.46594238281, 1214.94274902344, 1215.39904785156, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, 1209.25732421875, 1208.86218261719, 1209.048828125, 
                                                      1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1211.82763671875, 1215.14599609375, 
                                                      1215.67370605469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.06079101562, 1209.17163085938, 
                                                      1208.79455566406, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1213.59326171875, 
                                                      1220.58471679688, 1217.48803710938, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.30834960938, 
                                                      1209.05725097656, 1210.30346679688, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
                                                      1215.83471679688, 1222.40283203125, 1218.2578125, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, 1209.61926269531, 1210.16052246094, 1210.56823730469, 
                                                      1210.79309082031, 1210.46276855469, 1214.73291015625, 1216.96398925781, 
                                                      1219.07653808594, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.46716308594, 1209.22875976562, 
                                                      1210.47521972656, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1212.83312988281, 
                                                      1216.43481445312, 1219.17358398438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.00036621094, 
                                                      1209.9521484375, 1209.96520996094, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
                                                      1213.79821777344, 1217.90661621094, 1219.22473144531, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, 1209.54418945312, 1210.26818847656, 1210.0283203125, 
                                                      1210.03039550781, 1210.0283203125, 1212.66833496094, 1216.18420410156, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, 1209.45166015625, 1209.70434570312, 1209.33239746094, 
                                                      1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.15905761719, 1212.17797851562, 
                                                      1214.48999023438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.94604492188, 1210.36206054688, 
                                                      1210.103515625, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.44226074219, 
                                                      1214.18041992188, NA, NA), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, 
                       fromdisk = FALSE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
                       haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1207.15441894531, max = 1223.90710449219, 
                       band = 1L, unit = "", names = "nakkhu_hosp_10m"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
                                                                                      type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
                                                                                      names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
            extent = new("Extent", xmin = 333003.9801, xmax = 333403.9801, 
                         ymin = 3060402.4038, ymax = 3060602.4038), rotated = FALSE, 
            rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
              NULL), ncols = 40L, nrows = 20L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
            history = list(), z = list())

fp <- sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(333350,3060410)) # starting point
lp <- sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(333100,3060600)) # end point
```

Comment: Edited to add barriers. Curious to see if the solution works on your larger dataset. It runs on the smaller raster, but doesn't appear to change the LCP. I might have missed a step.

Comment: It looks like it worked. I have a few questions. If you could explain the answers, that would be great.

One every basic question - Doesn't the least-cost path, as the same suggests, represent the mildest slope path, the opposite of what I am looking for?

Second question - Shouldn't I use 'neighbours = 8' as opposed to the default value of 16 as I am only looking at the surrounding 8 cells at a time? I tried with both and they give different paths.

Comment: Good questions. Re `neighbors = 8` you are correct, at least when I read the docs I come to the same conclusion as you. As for your second question, its kind of a mind bender. I guess I'm realizing I don't know how a slope is calculated on a raster, and how slope translates to D8 flow.

Comment: If you are trying to calculate a flow path, I think ultimately you are going to be better off going with a GIS program as advised [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/355215/162034), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/84694/162034) and [here](https://fishandwhistle.net/post/2020/calculating-lake-outlets-using-r/). The tricky/non-standard part of your question is the predefined end point.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data, here called mamu_rast:

```
mamu_flow <- terra::terrain(mamu_rast, v = 'flow_dir)
plot(mamu_rast)
plot(mamu_flow, add = TRUE)
```

In my plots, white boxes clearly, or nearly follow your above least cost path, which I supposed could be extracted from mamu_flow, and replotted over mamu_rast. There seems a slight 'outlet' elevation problem at the end of the 'river' that may be an artifact of approach to original data. Very last cells are higher than river...

I don't publish my plots as I've blown up fontconfig so all local plots appear non-sensical. `flowdir` uses 8 neighbors and ties are broken at random. 16 neighbors may point to another approach to tie-breaking, but I don't know.

For your interesting, 'big crooked river' in response above, perhaps dput(case_2) for use with 'flow_dir'.

As the output of 'flow_dir' is deemed disappointing, using an actual hydro package might improve, here `topmodel`, whose virtue (among many) is that it is well established and returns a scarcer raster:

```
library(raster)
library(topmodel)

mamu_mtx <- raster::as.matrix(mamu_rast)
mamu_topidx <- topidx(mamu_mtx, resolution=10)
#returns 2 lists,atb (akin to slope) area (drainage to flow by cell)
#one then fishes around for values that seem to make sense
#but it's a river so the fishing is good
manu_top_b3_a1k <- river(mamu_mtx, atb=mamu_topidx$atb,area=mamu_topidx$area, res=10, thatb=3, tharea=1000)
#make it a raster again
mamu_top_b3_a1k_rast <- raster(mamu_top_be_a1k, template=mamu_rast)
#get river cells
river_cells <- Which(mamu_top_b3_a1k_rast, cells=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
xyFromCell(mamu_top_b3_a1k_rast, cell=river_cells)
          x       y
[1,] 333079 3060597
[2,] 333089 3060587
[3,] 333099 3060577
[4,] 333149 3060547
[5,] 333159 3060547
[6,] 333249 3060517
[7,] 333309 3060427
```

The delicious agony of constructing spatiallines from spatialpoints is left to the reader. One might argue that my outlet point isn't there. At which point one can either append or swap points. I'm less inclined to argue the model with generations of hydrologists.

Another approach, assuming one has tracked down `ALPSMLC30_N027E085_DSM.tif` from the JAXA Japanese satellite data portal, then in terminal:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=44 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" ALPSMLC30_N027E085_DSM.tif nep27_85.tif
# clip to area around hospital
gdalwarp -te 924530.12 3066804.08 925299.38 3067322.88 nep27_85.tif nakhu_hosp_bend30.tif
Creating output file that is 26P x 18L.
Processing nep27_85.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

returning to R:

```
nakhu_hosp <- raster('./N027E085/N027E085/nakhu_hosp_bend30.tif')
nakhu_hosp <- readAll(nakhu_hosp) #so we have values for dput()

dput(nakhu_hosp2)
new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "INT2S", 
    byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, NAchanged = FALSE, 
    nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
    blockrows = 18L, blockcols = 26L, driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), 
    data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = c(1286L, 1283L, 1281L, 
    1282L, 1282L, 1282L, 1286L, 1288L, 1287L, 1287L, 1288L, 1287L, 
    1287L, 1295L, 1294L, 1292L, 1292L, 1290L, 1289L, 1289L, 1292L, 
    1293L, 1292L, 1294L, 1298L, 1298L, 1288L, 1284L, 1282L, 1282L, 
    1282L, 1282L, 1284L, 1287L, 1287L, 1287L, 1287L, 1287L, 1287L, 
    1292L, 1292L, 1290L, 1290L, 1288L, 1289L, 1291L, 1292L, 1293L, 
    1293L, 1294L, 1296L, 1300L, 1288L, 1285L, 1283L, 1282L, 1282L, 
    1281L, 1283L, 1285L, 1287L, 1287L, 1286L, 1286L, 1286L, 1288L, 
    1286L, 1287L, 1286L, 1286L, 1287L, 1291L, 1292L, 1292L, 1291L, 
    1291L, 1296L, 1300L, 1287L, 1285L, 1284L, 1284L, 1282L, 1282L, 
    1283L, 1284L, 1285L, 1285L, 1285L, 1286L, 1287L, 1288L, 1286L, 
    1288L, 1286L, 1286L, 1285L, 1287L, 1290L, 1292L, 1291L, 1289L, 
    1294L, 1297L, 1289L, 1286L, 1285L, 1285L, 1284L, 1283L, 1283L, 
    1283L, 1286L, 1286L, 1285L, 1285L, 1287L, 1289L, 1288L, 1288L, 
    1292L, 1288L, 1286L, 1286L, 1287L, 1288L, 1289L, 1289L, 1293L, 
    1295L, 1293L, 1289L, 1287L, 1286L, 1285L, 1286L, 1285L, 1285L, 
    1285L, 1285L, 1285L, 1285L, 1289L, 1291L, 1291L, 1291L, 1293L, 
    1288L, 1286L, 1286L, 1290L, 1290L, 1288L, 1291L, 1293L, 1295L, 
    1299L, 1294L, 1293L, 1292L, 1291L, 1291L, 1290L, 1288L, 1288L, 
    1289L, 1289L, 1290L, 1293L, 1292L, 1294L, 1293L, 1294L, 1290L, 
    1287L, 1286L, 1288L, 1289L, 1288L, 1293L, 1292L, 1293L, 1300L, 
    1299L, 1297L, 1299L, 1297L, 1298L, 1298L, 1297L, 1297L, 1300L, 
    1298L, 1299L, 1297L, 1294L, 1295L, 1295L, 1293L, 1291L, 1286L, 
    1287L, 1289L, 1290L, 1293L, 1293L, 1295L, 1294L, 1301L, 1299L, 
    1300L, 1303L, 1299L, 1301L, 1303L, 1302L, 1301L, 1303L, 1303L, 
    1301L, 1301L, 1297L, 1296L, 1296L, 1294L, 1294L, 1285L, 1287L, 
    1291L, 1292L, 1290L, 1290L, 1293L, 1291L, 1301L, 1299L, 1302L, 
    1303L, 1302L, 1304L, 1305L, 1304L, 1303L, 1303L, 1302L, 1302L, 
    1303L, 1302L, 1302L, 1298L, 1295L, 1294L, 1284L, 1287L, 1288L, 
    1291L, 1293L, 1295L, 1292L, 1292L, 1300L, 1300L, 1302L, 1303L, 
    1301L, 1304L, 1305L, 1304L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1304L, 1305L, 
    1310L, 1306L, 1302L, 1299L, 1293L, 1289L, 1286L, 1287L, 1287L, 
    1290L, 1291L, 1292L, 1297L, 1301L, 1303L, 1302L, 1302L, 1301L, 
    1305L, 1305L, 1304L, 1304L, 1302L, 1302L, 1307L, 1310L, 1309L, 
    1305L, 1301L, 1299L, 1294L, 1289L, 1286L, 1287L, 1286L, 1289L, 
    1291L, 1295L, 1299L, 1305L, 1303L, 1303L, 1304L, 1301L, 1305L, 
    1305L, 1304L, 1304L, 1305L, 1304L, 1308L, 1312L, 1312L, 1306L, 
    1301L, 1298L, 1295L, 1289L, 1286L, 1286L, 1287L, 1293L, 1293L, 
    1292L, 1296L, 1301L, 1303L, 1303L, 1306L, 1304L, 1306L, 1303L, 
    1304L, 1305L, 1306L, 1309L, 1313L, 1315L, 1311L, 1304L, 1301L, 
    1298L, 1293L, 1288L, 1286L, 1286L, 1288L, 1292L, 1294L, 1294L, 
    1295L, 1305L, 1305L, 1305L, 1305L, 1306L, 1305L, 1304L, 1305L, 
    1305L, 1306L, 1314L, 1316L, 1314L, 1310L, 1305L, 1302L, 1299L, 
    1291L, 1287L, 1288L, 1287L, 1289L, 1290L, 1292L, 1292L, 1295L, 
    1306L, 1307L, 1307L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1305L, 1305L, 1308L, 
    1312L, 1314L, 1316L, 1315L, 1309L, 1307L, 1303L, 1298L, 1292L, 
    1288L, 1288L, 1288L, 1287L, 1289L, 1290L, 1295L, 1298L, 1305L, 
    1307L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1310L, 1309L, 1311L, 1314L, 1317L, 
    1319L, 1320L, 1315L, 1313L, 1311L, 1305L, 1301L, 1293L, 1289L, 
    1288L, 1288L, 1287L, 1288L, 1288L, 1289L, 1293L, 1306L, 1306L, 
    1306L, 1310L, 1309L, 1307L, 1310L, 1318L, 1319L, 1320L, 1324L, 
    1322L, 1318L, 1313L, 1311L, 1309L, 1304L, 1294L, 1291L, 1289L, 
    1288L, 1289L, 1289L, 1288L, 1288L, 1289L), offset = 0, gain = 1, 
        inmemory = TRUE, fromdisk = FALSE, isfactor = FALSE, 
        attributes = list(), haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1281L, 
        max = 1324L, band = 1L, unit = "", names = "nakhu_hosp_bend30"), 
    legend = new(".RasterLegend", type = character(0), values = logical(0), 
        color = logical(0), names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), 
    title = character(0), extent = new("Extent", xmin = 924530.12, 
        xmax = 925299.38, ymin = 3066804.08, ymax = 3067322.88), 
    rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), 
        transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 26L, nrows = 18L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=44 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())

summary(nakhu_hosp)
        nakhu_hosp_bend30
Min.                 1281
1st Qu.              1288
Median               1293
3rd Qu.              1303
Max.                 1324
NA's                    0
```

We pick a plausible drainage value, say 1288m and create a raster layer that sets values above that to NA:

```
nakhu_drainage <- clamp(nakhu_hosp, upper=1288, useValues = FALSE)
# make matrix for raster::reclassify
m <- c(1281, 1288, 1288)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
drain_1288 <- reclassify(nakhu_drain, rclmat)
drain_1288_poly <- rasterToPolygons(drain_1288, n=8, dissolve=TRUE)
plot(drain_1288_poly)
```

[image: drain_1288_poly]
Well, close, but want to drop out that dangling two pixels. So, reaching into this object and grab what I want (happily just a short list of polys):

```
drain_poly_I_want <- drainage_poly@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]
# to SpatialPolygon
drain_SP <- SpatialPolygons(Srl=list(Polygons(list(srl = drain_poly_I_want), ID='1')), proj4string=CRS(as.character(nakhu_hosp@crs)))

library(deldir)
tessel1 <- deldir(x= drain_1288_poly@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,1],
y= drain_1288_poly@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,2]) 

# using clipp in `tile.list`, note doesn't like valid polygons
# i.e. drop either first or last @coord

drain_tiles <- tile.list(tessel1, clipp = list(x = drain_1288_poly@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[1:220,1], y = drain_1288_poly@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[1:220,2]))
plot(drain_tiles[1:131])
```

[image: drain_tiles from plot order]
Now find some points along the outer edges and make a line,to and from the above endpoints.

Comment: `mamu_flow` will only give a raster with coded directions of the flow. While it's the first step in the right direction, it's not the final result (i.e. a polyline connecting start and endpoints using the steepest ascent) I am looking for. Thank you though.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. I am yet to the second approach. I am trying to develop a general procedure and am not sure I can adapt this procedure as some of the steps might need manual inputs. 
BTW, what does nakhu_hosp2 raster represent here? Is it some kind of coded cells according to drainage?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was just in case `nakhu_hosp <- raster::readALL(nakhu` surprised in some way, but should have edited. I didn't upsample the 30m  to 10m as you did. For a general solution, I would definitely advise a river stretch with more slope. Also, topmodel has a `sinkfill` function that is quite handy for preprocessing.